# methods in same file or in different file? which is better?

Tags: c#, class, object

I have one method to add dynamic controls on page of mobile screen which is used in each page. I can use this method in two ways

1) Write this method in each page in class of that page and use them directly without creating any object of that class.
eg.

```
// file: Page.cs
class Page()
{
    //declaration   
    void method()
    {
        // definition
    }

    //use here without object 
    method();
}
```

2) Write this method in a different file and different class and then use this method in each pageclass creating object of that class.
eg.

```
// file: Controls.cs
class Controls
{
    //declaration   
        void method()
    {
        //defination
    }

    //other fields and methods are also here which will not use     //all time but will occupy memory each time when i wll creat        //objects of this class
}

// file: Page.cs
class Page
{
    //use here creating object
    Controls obj = new Controls();
    obj.method();
}
```

in 1) Code become larger but no need of new object creation.

in 2) Code become small but need to create object each time which will occupy memory of all methods of Control class

so which one is better?

Comment: Have a common (abstract base) class that implements the (protected) method and have all pages inherit from that? Will also be usefull for any other stuff that all pages have in common. Another way would be static class/method, but that just feels wrong in this case.

Comment: the methods have same functionality each time which i want to use. In abstract base class i can only declare a method and have to define same method in each class again and again.I cannot use inheritance because my class is already inherited by .net created class which is from metadata which cannot be edited.so in which way I should go?

Comment: *sigh*, very ugly, but if there's no other way: `public static class PageControl { public static void method() { //... } }`. No need to create an object everytime, just call `PageControl.method()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class inheritance

```
public class PageBase
{
    protected void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class MyPage : PageBase
{
    public void DoMore()
    {
        this.DoSomething();
        //and more..
    }
}
```

Comment: yaa but in mycase my class is 
class DevicePage : PhoneApplicationPage
it is alreay inherited and Class PhoneApplicationPage is from metadata -which is created by .net and can not be edited. So what to do?

Comment: and also one class cannot have two parent class in inheritance

Comment: also PageBase can inherited from `class PageBase : PhoneApplicationPage`

Comment: Error : Partial declarations of 'vUrja_Mobile_Json.DevicePage' must not specify different base classes
This error comes from that....